# Pull Table Table Data preg_match

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-match, file-get-contents

Please visit this first : http://www.sportingpulse.com/comp_info.cgi?c=1-5917-0-232432-0&a=STATS&sgroup=floor

This is a more of a "is this even possible type question". I have created a small script to pull off data from a sports website.

```
$url = "http://www.sportingpulse.com/comp_info.cgi?c=1-5917-0-232432-0&a=STATS&sgroup=floor";

preg_match_all('#<table[^>]+>[\w\W]*?</table>#i', file_get_contents($url), $match);
$tableone = $match[0][0];
$tabletwo = $match[0][1];

$tableone1 = preg_replace('/<a href=\"(.*?)\">(.*?)<\/a>/', "\\2", $tableone);
echo $tableone1;
```

This works great and puts all the table data into my website but what i was wondering is it possible to only pull off only team SOL results instead of everyones?

Could anyone point me in the right direction, the only thing i can think using is to look for "SOL" then somehow grab the tr behind it?

Thanks

Comment: This looks like a job for Dom documents and XPath Queries.  See http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php and http://php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$url = "http://www.sportingpulse.com/comp_info.cgi?c=1-5917-0-232432-0&a=STATS&sgroup=floor";
$str = file_get_contents($url);
$doc = @DOMDocument::loadHTML($str);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$entries = $xpath->query('//html/body/div[@id="site-wrap"]/div[@id="content-wrap"]/div[@id="col-1-2-wrap"]/div[@id="content"]/div[@class="tableContainer"]/div/table/tbody/tr[td[2]/a/text()="SOL"]');
echo '<table>';
foreach($entries as $entry) {
  echo($doc->saveXML($entry));
}
echo '</table>';
```

Comment: Wow this worked perfectly, could you please explain how this works, I hate not knowing how something works when using it. Cheeers

Comment: The path up to `tr` is given with condition to select `tr` as `where SOL is the text inside <a> tag inside second <td>`. so only those `tr` are selected.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I couldn't make this more complete, but I'm about to get on a flight.  Try this to start:

```
$url = "http://www.sportingpulse.com/comp_info.cgi?c=1-5917-0-232432-0&a=STATS&sgroup=floor";
$html = file_get_contents($url);
$doc = DOMDocument::loadHTML($html);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

$query = "/your/xpath/query/here";

$entries = $xpath->query($query);
```

Check out this link for details on xpath queries.  http://php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php
And another great reference: http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp

I'll check back and add more detail after I land.

Answer (score 0):

I use http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/ for things like that. You can then iterate over every tr inside that table and check if the  link of the second td(in your case) is == SOL. If so you can read the data from the next tds. See http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm for that. If you need further help I can give you a code sample.

Best Regards
Stephan S.

Comment: From what i can find you can only find stuff with ID's/Class's as this will not have any just text saying SOL. What it needs to do is find all the TR's with SOL inside and loop through them if thats possible.